# java switch jumps into more than 1 case

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a Switch case, where more than 1 case is invoked.
I was looking wether two of the int-konstants in the cases are the same or if the case is invoked more than once that I didn't expect, but it isn't.

So I put in a few "syso"s:

```
  System.out.println("Switch");
  System.out.println(key.ID);
  switch (key.ID) {
  case Key.ID_ROTATE:
     // do stuff
     break;
  case Key.ID_LEFT:
     // do stuff
     break;
  case Key.ID_HIDE:
     System.out.println(Key.ID_HIDE);
     // do stuff
  case Key.ID_PAUSE:
     System.out.println(Key.ID_PAUSE);
     // do stuff
     break;
  case Key.ID_RESTART:
     // do stuff
     break;
  }
  System.out.println("Switch end");
```

Output is:

`Switch`

`6`

`6`

`7`

`Switch end`

So the value of the switch is 6 and java is invoking case 6 and 7.
My question is just why?

Comment: Because you forgot a `break;` in the ID_HIDE case.

Comment: `case Key.ID_HIDE:` have no break

Comment: Omg! Yes thanks. Always the small things!

Comment: Also add a default block to make the code better

Comment: Do you mean an empty default block is better than none? If yes, why?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `break` statement at the end of `ID_HIDE`'s case:

```
case Key.ID_HIDE:
    System.out.println(Key.ID_HIDE);
    // do stuff
    break; // Was missing in the original code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case Key.ID_HIDE:
    System.out.println(Key.ID_HIDE);
   // do stuff   You forget the break statement.
```